# Npm install angular/cli error EPERM Operation not permitted

Tags: node.js, angular-cli

> 4399 error Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink
>   'C:\Users\deven\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules.staging\tmp-5fcc012e\README.md'
>   4399 error  { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink
>   'C:\Users\deven\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules.staging\tmp-5fcc012e\README.md'
>   4399 error   cause: 4399 error    { Error: EPERM: operation not
>   permitted, unlink
>   'C:\Users\deven\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules.staging\tmp-5fcc012e\README.md'
>   4399 error      errno: -4048, 4399 error      code: 'EPERM', 4399
>   error      syscall: 'unlink', 4399 error      path:
>   'C:\Users\deven\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\tmp-5fcc012e\README.md'
>   }, 4399 error   stack: 'Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink
>   \'C:\Users\deven\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\tmp-5fcc012e\README.md\'',
>   4399 error   errno: -4048, 4399 error   code: 'EPERM', 4399 error
>   syscall: 'unlink', 4399 error   path:
>   'C:\Users\deven\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\tmp-5fcc012e\README.md',
>   4399 error   parent: '@angular/cli' } 4400 error The operation was
>   rejected by your operating system. 4400 error It's possible that the
>   file was already in use (by a text editor or antivirus), 4400 error or
>   that you lack permissions to access it. 4400 error 4400 error If you
>   believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
>   4400 error permissions of the file and its containing directories, or
>   try running 4400 error the command again as root/Administrator (though
>   this is not recommended). 4401 verbose exit [ -4048, true ]

Comment: Permission issue - launch the command promt as a admin - right click on your cmd.exe and run as administrator and try .

Comment: Hi @devendra, welcome to StackOverflow. It's worth reading the "How can I write a good question?" guide seen here (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your question here provides the error which is good, but there's a lot more information you could provide to make it easier to get to an answer. Checkout the guide for more info.

Comment: hey, i am launching cmd as admin but still get the issue.

Answer (score 9):

Since you're using `Windows`, you have to launch the terminal **`as administrator`** and retry should work.

Comment: thanks selem, i always open command prompt and select the "run as administrator" and then run "npm i -g @angular/cli". i tried many times npm clean cache --force or uninstall node, delete npm-cache and npm folder and then reinstall node but no success.

Comment: Are you running you node app behind any corporate proxy?

Answer (score 2):

It seems like this is a problem with npm. Try deleting your node_modules folder and running `npm install` again. This should fix the problem.

Comment: i tried many times by deleting folder npm and npm cache, uninstall node and then reinstall but that doesn't fix my problem. i am installing the stable version of node v8.12.0 and npm 6.4.1

Answer (score 2):

It may be possible that your package.json is open in some editor. Close it and then run the npm command again.

Answer (score 1):

Try to uninstall the CLI using:

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
```

and reinstall using:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

and also try to update `npm` to latest version

```
npm cache clean --force

npm install -g npm@latest
```

Answer (score 1):

It solved for me when I made this: Right-click on -*What ever program I use*- and select Run as Administrator.
Personally I made it on PowerShell, but I assume that it works this way on any program

Answer (score 0):

1. Launch your code editor (eg.. Visual Studio Code) as Administrator.
2. npm install -g @vue/cli.
3. vue create yourprojectname.

Answer (score 0):

Please try following steps:

1. Delete node_modules
2. Do npm cache clean --force
3. Restart the PC
4. Try again **npm install**, now modules will install without any issues

(optional) - If you are behind VPN and not using any private registry , exit VPN and do **npm install** after restarting pc

Answer (score 0):

Okay, for me running as the administrator did not work at all. Nothing worked until I went into my root/global folder as shown below:

C:\Users\MyName

and in that folder I deleted the node_modules folder and any Angular config files that were globally put there.  After doining that I went back to my local folder and it worked perfectly.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

I had opened the project in multiple terminals. Later after closing all the respective terminals and running 'npm i', things started to work well.