# Service Fabic - Cannot run Angular Locally on Windows: EPERM: operation not permitted

Tags: c#, angular, azure-service-fabric

I have installed service fabic locally for testing. As a dummy first run I have simply created a single c# app with angular front end. Zero changes. Out the box.

When I run it I get the following.

```
    An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (One or more errors occurred. (The npm script 'start' exited without indicating that the Angular CLI was listening for requests. The error output was: Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\npm'

Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\npm'

))
System.Threading.Tasks.Task<TResult>.GetResultCore(bool waitCompletionNotification)

InvalidOperationException: The npm script 'start' exited without indicating that the Angular CLI was listening for requests. The error output was: Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\npm'

Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\npm'

Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.AngularCli.AngularCliMiddleware.StartAngularCliServerAsync(string sourcePath, string scriptName, string pkgManagerCommand, int portNumber, ILogger logger, DiagnosticSource diagnosticSource, CancellationToken applicationStoppingToken)
```

I can run the same template project out of service fabric. And on my machine in general. So does anyone know why this is the case here.

Comment: it sounds like a permissions problem, maybe this link can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34600932/npm-eperm-operation-not-permitted-on-windows

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue, we must use the workarounds listed below.

Set your environment to Production and see what happens. As of your error i believe that it has something to do with attempting an NPM start.

```xml
<environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Production" />
```

& For more information please refer the below links-

SO thread :  [EPERM: Operation not permitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56234007/eperm-operation-not-permitted-npm-angular-7-on-iis-with-backend-net-core-2-1) &  [Npm install angular/cli error EPERM Operation not permitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53087328/npm-install-angular-cli-error-eperm-operation-not-permitted)

GitHub issue : [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\npm](https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/issues/1612#issuecomment-427099282)